# How to get list of tables names and alias from Doctrine Querybuilder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

i'am working with Prestashop 1.7 framework and i'am stuck here any help ?

```
  public function hookActionCustomerGridQueryBuilderModifier(array $params){
       $searchQueryBuilder = $params['search_query_builder'];
       // tables names
       //$tablesList = $searchQueryBuilder->getTables();
       // echo var_dump($tablesList);
   }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @lemon i already solve it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
$searchQueryBuilder->getQueryParts()['from'];
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).